# Selichot vs tikkun hatsot

Tags: tefilla, selichot, tikkun-chatzot

The Yalkut Yosef says that praying tikkun hatsot-- a perhaps 15 minute tefilla focusing on the Hurban-- is preferable to selichot-- a 45 minute tefilla on Rachamim *with the 13 middot of Rachamim*?

Did Rav Ovadya mean this le'chatchila (in the ideal)?

הלכות ראש השנה - סימן תקפא - מדיני הסליחות

> ט. תלמידי חכמים ובני ישיבות שאינם קמים
> יום יום לסליחות, אם הולכים לישון אחר חצות לילה, מה טוב שיאמרו קצת
> סליחות לפני שישנו, אפילו ביחידות, וכן יאמרו תיקון חצות קודם השינה,
> **> ומעלת תיקון חצות חשובה יותר מאמירת סליחות עם הצבור.**
> [חזון עובדיה על
> ימים נוראים עמוד י]

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.581.4?lang=bi

Answer (score 1):

This only applies to one who regularly recited Tikkun Chatzos, but both come from Minhagim. Tikkun Chatzos was not a universally accepted practice, while Selichos was, thus in an ordinary situation Selichos would precede. In the ideal, if one is already getting up at Chatzos for Selichos, Ma Tov U'Ma No'im if he can recite both.

והגר"ח קניבסקי מובא בדעת נוטה ט עונה: כרצונו – רשם מ"צ.

Comment: Is Rav Chayim debating Rav Ovadya, or clarifying Rav Ovadya's opinion?

Comment: He is clarifying Rav Ovadia's opinion, in his opinion. What R' Ovadia would respond, I wish I would know!